# Microsoft Word - Insert text from JavaScript/JScript ActiveX

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-interop, activexobject

I want to use JavaScript (on a web page) to insert some text into a Microsoft Word document.  [The Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b9478cs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y1938) has sample code for VB and C#, but not for JavaScript (JScript).  I've been able to figure out a lot of it using code samples [as seen here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but certain lines are messing me up.

Here's what I've got so far:

var retText;

```
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var wordApp = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
wordApp.Documents.Add();

if (wordApp.Application.Options.Overtype) {
    wordApp.Options.Overtype = false;
}
```

But when it comes to this line (in C#), I can't quite get at how to translate it:

```
if (currentSelection.Type == Word.WdSelectionType.wdSelectionIP)
```

`currentSelection.Type` can be translated to `wordApp.Selection.Type` in my code above, but I'm not sure what to do with `Word.WdSelectionType.wdSelectionIP`.

Some failed attempts:

```
alert(wordApp.WdSelectionType); //undefined
alert(new ActiveXObject("Word.WdSelectionType"); //errors out
alert(wordApp.ActiveDocument.WdSelectionType); //undefined
```

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks The security on our intranet is turned way down; we already have some text-inserting code based on the Word.Basic API, but I think I need some features that cannot be used with that one.  Or is there a separate security role regarding that WdSelectionType stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think COM enums are accessible from Javascript.

Instead, you can use the constant's numeric value, which you can find in the VBA object browser.
For readable code, you can make a Javascript variable holdign the value instead of just writing a number.

Comment: Bummer.  Thanks, though; I guess I don't really need to worry too much about it.  This object browser is pretty cool, by the way.